# Develop "You are tring to download files too quickly" in my webpage

Tags: php, javascript, download, html

I have a web page (HTML, php, javascript) with some direct download links.
I would like to block users that are clicking all these download links in a short time.

I would like something like that:
1) click on a link -> direct download
2-a) click on another link too quickly -> redirect to a new page with a text "please wait a bit before downloading another file"
2-b) click on another link after a X time -> direct download

Please suggest me how to do this (simpler method, not needed to be an "high security" one, just to limit accidental clicks).
Thank you

Comment: Just one question: why?

Comment: If you are using sessions, store latest download start time there and when new request comes compare it. Also you can disable the dl buttons via js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using [`sessions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php), then "*save a last download time in it*" is a way:

```
$limit = 3; // seconds
$now   = time();
$last  = isset($_SESSION['download-stamp']) ? $_SESSION['download-stamp'] : 0;

if($now - $last < $limit){
    header('Location: wait.html');
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['download-stamp'] = $now;

// flush file
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not experienced with PHP sessions but it seems a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

1. Identify a user somehow (e.g. with a cookie (can be deleted) or their IP address (could be shared better users)).
2. Log downloads in a database against a timestamp
3. `COUNT(*) from downloads WHERE identifier=? and timestamp <= ?`

Answer (score 0):

You could check the time with javascript when the user clicks on a download link and compare it to a specified duration. If the exceeding duration is larger, redirect to a page or alert some information.

Comment: Which is easily circumvented, as it is JavaScript.

Comment: @BartFriederichs That may be the case, but the question specifies "not needed to be an "high security" one [solution], just to limit accidental clicks"

Comment: Which can be spoofed easily....

Comment: @thefrontender I get it. Still makes me wonder, why go all this trouble to avoid "accidental clicks" ?